# Getting Current Song Data From Windows Media Player 12

Tags: vb.net, media, media-player

I have been searching all over for an answer to this, and I'm figuring there is no way to do it, but I thought I'd ask.

I'm looking to make a VB.net app that gets and displays the artist and title of a song playing in Windows Media Player. I'm not looking to embed the player in my app, just pull data from the already existing window.

Most of the stuff I find on how to do this is old or related to embedding WMP. I'm looking to do it in with MWP12. I've also seen references to using AxWindowsMediaPlayer.currentMedia Property, but that doesn't seem to work anymore. I used to be able to pull the data from the Registry, but it seems Microsoft took that away.

I've tried sooooo much other code, but this is currently what I have. I'm at my wits end.

```
Imports WMPLib

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim wmp As WindowsMediaPlayer = New WindowsMediaPlayer
        Dim playlist As IWMPPlaylist = wmp.currentMedia.???????(????).Item(?)
        Label1.Text = playlist.getItemInfo("Title")
    End Sub

End Class
```

No idea where to go here, but thanks for any help.